# Can an unsupported device become supported?

Tags: arcore

I wanted to play Minecraft Earth beta on my Xiaomi mi A2 lite but as you can check on the full list of supported devices, my phone isn't one of them.

My question is: Is it possible that in some way a previously not supported phone becomes supported with an update (phone update/arcore update/maybe something else)?

For now I'm playing with an APK of arcore I found online so the game boots without telling me I need arcore, but as soon as I have to use AR, it's just a blank screen.

Comment: "Is it possible that in some way a previously not supported phone becomes supported with an update (phone update/arcore update/maybe something else)" that depends on the reason it's unsupported, such as inadequate hardware (in which case it's unlikely) or because the developers want to test the hardware first and otherwise don't supported it by default.

Comment: According to this GitHub thread, the Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite does not support arcore because Xiaomi hasn't made the moves to support it, and that it isn't Google's fault: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/553

Comment: Weird, because there are still some other Xiaomi devices on the list. I'll try to look for a way of making my phone compatible, maybe rooting it if necessary, I just hope it's just a software problem rather that a hardware problem.